# shell: Extract key value from a string with known key

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a script inside which the following command is run:

```sh
OUTPUT=`echo "User-Name=$username,User-Password=$passwd" | radclient $ip auth $key`
echo $OUTPUT
```

After executing the command I get the following result in `OUTPUT`.

```sh
Received response ID 239, code 2, length = 34
        Reply-Message = "Hello, root"
```

Then I check whether the `OUPUT` contains **"code"**:

```sh
if grep -wq code <<< $OUTPUT; then    
    echo "Success"
    break;
fi
```

This also works.

Now if my `OUTPUT` variable contains **code** then I want to extract the code value: **2** (in above case)

How can this be achieved:

So Input:

```
Received response ID 239, code 2, length = 34
            Reply-Message = "Hello, root"
```

Output: **2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $OUTPUT | sed -n 's/.*code \([^,]\+\),.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: This also means you don't need the `grep`. The output of this command will be the code if there is one, but nothing if there is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in bash, it has regular expression support, in your case it could go something like this:

```
read A < <(echo 'Received response ID 239, code 2, length = 34')
if [[ "$A" =~ ^Received\ response\ ID\ [0-9]+,\ code\ ([0-9]+),\ length\ =\ ([0-9]+) ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; else echo nope; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${OUTPUT}" | sed -e '/.*, code \([^,]\{1,\}\).*/ !d' -e 's//\1/'
```

posix compliant, so will work on any recent sed